# How to loop through multidimensional associative javascript array?

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have 'multidimensional associative' javascript array (which in fact is object with properties as JS can't have native associative array):

```
var multiArray={ AAA:"one", BBB:"two", CCC:{ 0:"xxx", 1:"yyy", 2:"zzz"} };
```

And i need to get such string from this array:

'AAA=one & BBB=two & CCC=xxx,yyy,zzz'

How do I do that?

If i use two simple loops like this:

```
for(var key in multiArray)
{
        for(var subkey in multiArray[key])
        {
            string = string + multiArray[key][subkey]+",";
        }
}
```

I get something like this:

'AAA = o,n,e & BBB = t,w,o & CCC = xxx, yyy,zzz'

Which is not what i need.

Any solutions using Javascript **only**?

Comment: Why is `multiArray['CCC']` not an array?

Comment: *as JS can't have native associative array* Interesting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @KooiInc Javascript has indexed arrays and objects. That's probably what Andrew means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a function like

```
var multiArray={ AAA:"one", BBB:"two", CCC:{ 0:"xxx", 1:"yyy", 2:"zzz"} };

function objToStr(o,delim) {
    if (/^(string|boolean|number)$/.test(typeof o)) return o;
    delim = delim || '&'; // delimiter
    var arr = [], isArray = true;
    for (var j in o) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(j))) { isArray = false; break; }
    }
    if (isArray) {
        for (var j in o) arr[j] = objToStr(o[j],delim);
        return arr.join(',');
    }
    for (var j in o) {
        if (typeof o[j] != 'object') arr.push(j+'='+o[j]);
        else arr.push(j+'='+objToStr(o[j],delim));
    }
    return arr.join(delim);
}
console.log(objToStr(multiArray,'&'))
```

**EDIT:** You will need to escape necessary characters here if this is going to be a GET query. Also, I'm not sure what you're expecting as the result of the following array so I couldn't write the best code that will suit your needs.

```
var multiArray={ AAA:"one", BBB:"two", CCC:{ 0:"xxx", 1:"yyy", 2:{a:1, b:2}} };
```

Comment: Although Parth's answer has correct key point, his result string is not exactly correct. Your function returns what I exactly wanted. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Though it's not final because of those 2 points I mentioned in the lower, edit section.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i've created a fiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ6HH/.
It works for any depth of nestedness.

Comment: Yes, this answer works. The key here is to check if property is object: 'if(typeof o[k] == 'object')' ;

Comment: then why did someone downvote this? I know inhan's answer is more involved and detailed, but for this simple scenario, i found my method simpler...

Comment: Yeah I agree, your code is actually better. I just added the array functionality in my suggestion. I wouldn't downvote your solution. Somebody must have mistakenly done that.

Comment: @Andrew `typeof o[k] == 'object'` in a way accomplishes that. But it it were an indexed array you would need to use `o[k] instanceof Array` instead since the **Array** class extends **Object**.